Forwarding requests to different verticle based on path param (Vert.x)
I'm using Vert.x for the first time ever to try to build an API in Java. Right now I can use an eventBus in my main verticle to forward certain routes like /example/:name etc to a handler that sends an eventBus message to it's respective verticle.
  void helloPOC(RoutingContext context) {
    vertx
        .eventBus()
        .request(
            "poc.hello",
            "",
            reply -> {
              context.response().end((String) reply.result().body());
            });
  }

However, it doesn't make sense to have so many handlers in my main verticle. I don't assume this endpoint is going to be very fancy and have a lot of variables involved, but I want to be able to have a handler that can take all requests like /example/* to be handled in it's respective exampleVerticle.
I could find any resources to do so but essentially this is how some pseudocode for what I want to be able to do.
// mainVerticle.java

start(){
  router.get("/example/*").handler(this::exampleHandler);
}

exampleHandler(){
  // routes to exampleVerticle
}

//exampleVerticle.java
start(){
  router.get("/example/hello").handler(this::helloExample);
}

void helloExample(RoutingContext context) {
  vertx
      .eventBus()
      .request(
          "example.hello",
          "",
          reply -> {
            // some sort of reply
          });
}

Obviously I don't have much of an idea what I'm doing but I hope what I'm trying to do makes sense.
Thanks in advance!

Vert.x, as a toolkit and not a framework, does not prescribe how to organize your source code. You can do it as you like and it should work.
For example, you could put all your handlers in a utility class and wire them from another place:
public final class Handlers {
    private Handlers() {}

    public Handler<RoutingContext> getOranges() {
        return ctx -> ctx.end("Juicy Oranges");
    }

    public Handler<RoutingContext> getBananas() {
        return ctx -> ctx.end("Tasty Bananas");
    }
}

And in another Verticle:
router
    .get("/oranges").handler(Handlers.getOranges())
    .get("/bananas").handler(Handlers.getBananas());

Frankly, most of the time, I just deploy one HttpVerticle from my MainVerticle like so:
public final class HttpVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    
    public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) {
        var router = Router.router(vertx);
        router
            .get("/bananas").handler(this::handleBananas)
            .get("/oranges").handler(this::handleOranges);
        vertx.createHttpServer()
            .requestHandler(router)
            .listen(8080)
            .onSuccess(__ -> startPromise.complete(null))
            .onFailure(ex -> startPromise.fail(ex));
    }

}

And in MainVerticle:
public final class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) {
        vertx.deployVerticle(new HttpVerticle())
            .onSuccess(__ -> startPromise.complete(null))
            .onFailure(ex -> startPromise.fail(ex));
    }
}

